# Right Detail UITableViewCell not showing full lines on iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ipad

Happy Holidays everyone!

I have a simple application with a UITableViewController and multiple sections. Section 0 is using a Basic UITableViewStyle and Section 1 is using a Right Detail UITableViewStyle. On iPads only, I'm facing a really weird issue where the lines of the UITableView in Section 1 do not extend all the way till the end of the device, as depicted in the image below:

[image]

The  top section is Section 0, the Basic UITableViewStyle and the bottom section is the Right Detail UITableViewStyle.

Is this expected behaviour, a bug (latest Xcode and iOS 9.2), or is there an easy fix for this?

Please note, this is an iPad only problem because it looks fine on the iPhone, including the 6 Plus and it is the same behaviour on the simulator and on an iPad Air 2 device.

Any thoughts on this would be appreciated.

Update:

My code in this class:

```
- (UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Custom label for the section header titles
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15, 0, self.moreTabTableView.frame.size.width, 10)];
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    [label setFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:15.0]];

    if (section == 0)
    {
        label.text = @"Show Your Support";
    }
    else if (section == 1)
    {
        label.text = @"Connect with the BOS Team";
    }
    return label;
}
```

It's all created in Storyboard, so this is the only code for this class.

**Update**

I've looked at my code a bit more to see what's going on with this. I am using a custom class for the UITableViewCell (called CustomMoreTableViewCell) and I have this code only in that custom subclass:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 30, 30);
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(47, 11, 300, 21);
}
```

I am making sure the image is sized appropriately for each cell. I have just made the Donate cell to be the custom UITableViewCell subclass and it does the same thing with shortening the lines.

I'm able to reproduce this with the use of the custom UITableViewView subclass but I'm not sure what's required to make the lines go all the way (and I have tried a multitude of values for the imageView and textLabel).

Comment: Show your code, please. _You_ are the one who sets up the lines (separators). So how are you doing that?

Comment: Thanks @matt - I forgot to mention that I'm actually creating this entirely in Storyboard. My code (which I've shown in the question) is for the section titles only.

Comment: Can you post a reduced version of this part of the app on github or something, so that I can see the storyboard configuration? Or at least give instructions for reproducing it...

Comment: The problem is that when _I_ make a bunch of Right Detail cells configured in the storyboard, it doesn't look like your screen shot at all.

Comment: Hi @matt, I've never used GitHub before but the best way I can see to reproduce it (and I've tried again) is have a UITableViewController in storyboard with a UITableView with 2 sections, section one's table is Basic and section two's table is Right Detail. Remove the text from the "detail" label and make sure there's an image (UIImageView) associated with the UITableViewCell, which you can do in the inspector by assigning an image in the cell. Run on iPad (simulator should be enough to reproduce). Are you able to reproduce it at this point? (I hope so!)

Comment: Yes but what I'm telling you is that when I do that, the separator extends all the way to the right edge.

Comment: Thanks Matt. That's really weird and I'm not sure what's going on. I'm going to try tomorrow to just use right detail for all of the cells and I'll use a generic image on the top cells and see if that works

Comment: HI @matt - I have just updated the question with a bit more information on this - I'm using a custom subclass of the UITableViewCell and that looks to be what's causing this here.

Comment: Bravo! Now I can reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `layoutSubviews` implementation to look like this:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(8, 8, 30, 30);
    self.textLabel.frame = CGRectMake(47, 11, 300, 21);
    self.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
}
```

If the result is not precisely what you want, then adjust the `separatorInset` accordingly.

(However, the best approach would be to use a totally custom cell, and not to try to modify an existing built-in cell style as you are doing.)

Comment: Thanks very much @matt - That code worked like a charm. Also, I appreciate the advice and in order to make sure nothing goes wrong, I might just use Custom cells, but I really appreciate your work with this for now. Thank you!